# box-shadow disappears on hover with scaling img

Tags: html, css

I created a codepen so understanding my problem is easier.
I gave the image a `:before` to get a `box-shadow` on it, but if I hover over the `image`, it is supposed to scale up a little bit, which it does, but the `box-shadow` isn't supposed to disappear, which it does...

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/YyqjvJ

The shadow may stay where it is, or scale with the image, but not disappear.

HTML:

```
<a href="#0" style="height: 429px;">
  <figure><img alt="bild" src="http://lorempixel.com/410/230"></figure>
  <div>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 1px 0 0 1px;
    width: 490px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a:hover {
  img {
    transform: scale(1.04);
  }
}
figure {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
figure:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 227px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 1;
}
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    width: auto;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I switched the box-shadow to red and I can still see it when the image scales. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RWaBqd

Comment: It seems that this has been solved.

Comment: @paulie-d is the color all you have changed?

Comment: I actually don't see any shadow at all

Comment: @Rokin The shadow is inset, and covers all of the image. Change the rgba to 255,0,0 to see it.

Comment: @schndr.eu What browser are you using and on what system? Works fine here in SeaMonkey and Chromium under Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I changed the z-index and now it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `z-index: 1` to the `:before` solved my problem.

Comment: Me, Paulie and Bram all saw the shadow on hover, so what you were experiencing was probably due to a browser quirk.

Comment: I added the z-index. Remove it, than you can see the problem I had.